# getting to server on internal network with the external address

Tags: nat

I have a network behind a nat with exchange server.

Mobile device are configured to access exchange using its real address (the single ip that the entire office hides behind)

When the mobile device entets the office network they cant connect.

Safeoffice is the router behind the nat device.

I have added a route from internal network 192.168.1.0/24 to 44.44.44.44/32 next hop 192.168.1.50

Tried to ping 44.44.44.44 from inside and failed. Obviesly the 50 server will not respond to the 44.44.44.44 request.

Is there away to solve this without changing anytho
Ing on the mobile devices ?

Answer (score 1):

Your router is not going to like traffic going out, then back in.
If the mobile devices get the IP address from DNS, you can probably set your internal DNS server to give the internal address when they are on your network, but leave the public DNS to point  to the outside address.